# Mutliple select in Select Option in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails

How to select multiple values in options_from_collection_for_select in rails? Currently, I am choosing one value. I need to choose multiple values.

```
<select id="addr" class="form-control" tabindex="2" onchange="getSelectedDeviceType()" >
  <option value="">Select Device</option>
  <%= options_from_collection_for_select(@devices,:mac_address, :mac_address,:multiple => true) %>
</select>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For multiple selection you try

```
<select multiple>
 <option>1</option>
 <option>2</option>
</select>
```

You can refer to [this](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_select_multiple.asp) link for reference

You can use this js function

```
function getSelectedOptions(sel) {
var opts = [],
opt;
var len = sel.options.length;
for (var i = 0; i < len; i++) {
  opt = sel.options[i];
  if (opt.selected) {
    opts.push(opt);
  }
}

return opts;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.I am getting error  Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined

Comment: what are you passing for sel while invoking the method you need to pass this.value as the parameter if you want to use the above method

Comment: Thanks.Now getting value

Answer (score 0):

Rails way, you can try out with form f object:

```
<%= f.select :addr, options_from_collection_for_select(@devices,:mac_address, :mac_address,:multiple => true),  {prompt: 'Please select ...' }, { class: 'form-control', :onchange => "getSelectedDeviceType()" } %>
```

or with select_tag:

```
<%= select_tag 'addr', options_for_select(@devices.map { |s| [s.name, s.id] }), {multiple: true, :onchange => "getSelectedDeviceType()" %>
```